# is there a diffrence between port mapping and host network?

Tags: docker, nginx, networking

i have two commands:

1. docker run --name some-nginx -d -p 80:80 nginx
2. docker run --name some-nginx -d --network host nginx

In my understanding nginx will show default page on my computer's port 80

In my host machine localhost:80 works perfectly same: gives me default nginx page.

BUT when i try it on other LAN machine, if i type my-host-machinip:80, first one works but second one gives me "connection refuesed"

i can not understand why it happend.

Answer (score 2):

`--network host` allows the container to have access to the whole host network while the `-p 80:80` maps port 80 of the container to the port 80 of host

Comment: but when I connect to port 80 from the LAN machine two commands work differently

Comment: @jisoo the second connects the container to the host network only. you can pass the --ip of other machine with network flag :https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/